# is there a relation between regular graphs and power set graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

The title says it. Let $G(V,E)$ be a $k$-regular graph and $H(\hat{V},\hat{E})$ be the graph of the power set of $[k]$ elements (that is, $H$ resulted from the inclusion relation over the elements of $[k]$) for $k\geq 2$.

Is there any relation between the two? because when $k=3$ (i.e. cubic graph) I see they are isomorphic.

Comment: Surely it's clear that the power set graph for a set with $n$ elements is always $n$-regular?  Are you looking for more than that?

Comment: @MJD Thanks. Are they isomorphic for any $k\geq 2$? That is, If I have $k$-regular graph can I always say it is isomorphic to its counterpart ( the power set graph of $k$ elements)?

Comment: Are you aware that for $k>1$ there is more than one $k$-regular graph? For example, there is a 2-regular graph with $n$ vertices for each $n\ge2 $. But only the one with 4 vertices is isomorphic to the power set graph for a set of two elements.

Comment: @MJD Yes. In my case $G$ and $H$ have the same number of vertices and edges.

Comment: Are you aware that there are, in general, many $k$-regular graphs with $n$ vertices, for any given $k\ge 3$ and $n$?  For example, the power set graph for a 3-set has $k=3$ and $n=8$, but so does a graph with vertices $\{A,\ldots, H\}$,and edges $\{AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD,EF,EG,EH,FG,FH,GH \}$; also there is a 3-regular graph on 8 vertices that has vertices $\{A,\ldots, H\}$ and edges $AB, AF, AH, BC, BD, CF, CH, DE, DG, EF, EG, GH$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class of $k$-regular graphs is, in general, very large.  There is not, as you seem to suggest, a single $k$-regular graph for each $k$.  For each $k$, the class of $k$-regular graphs  includes the power set graph for a set with $k$ elements, but in general this is only one of the many members of the class of all $k$-regular graphs.

Here are some 3-regular graphs with 8 vertices.  Only the fourth from the left is the power set graph.

[image: Six 3-regular graphs with 8 vertices]

(Image adapted from [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicGraph.html).)

Comment: Thanks alot. *"For each k, the class of k-regular graphs includes the power set graph for a set with k elements"* is there any reference or pointers where I can read more about this ?